# ruby set Dynamic Class variables with mixins

Tags: ruby, mixins, class-variables

I need to define some class variables that set namespace and table class variables.

This is the mixin template I'm using:

```
module MyMixin
    module ClassMethods
        .... 
    end

    module InstanceMethods
        ....
    end

    def self.included(receiver)
        namespace, table = receiver.name.underscore.pluralize.split('/')
        receiver.extend         ClassMethods
        receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
end
```

For the code below, I would like to have class variables of **namespace: 'hello'** and **table: 'worlds'**

```
module Hello
    class World
        include MyMixin
    end
end
```

For the code below, I would like to have class variables of **namespace: 'goodbye'** and **table: 'friends'**

```
module Goodbye
    class Friend
        include MyMixin
    end
end
```

I tried using receiver.class_variable_set/get but when I load the **Goodbye::Friend** code, the class variables of **Hello::World**.

How can I set and separate both class variables?

Comment: `Hello` is not the same as `hello`. Please be conscious of capitalization, and be more reader friendly.

Comment: @sawa What do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I could use instance_variables to keep the separate **"class"** variables for my class that was instantiate through a mixin template.

```
module MyMixin
    module ClassMethods
        .... 
    end

    module InstanceMethods
        ....
    end

    def self.included(receiver)
        namespace, table = receiver.name.underscore.pluralize.split('/')
        receiver.extend         ClassMethods
        receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
        receiver.instance_variable_set :@namespace, namespace.to_sym
        receiver.instance_variable_set :@table, table.to_sym
        receiver.instance_variable_set :@properties, {}
    end
end
```